# Правильно вызвать метод у только что созданной через reflect структуры

Tags: golang

Приветствую.

Создаю объект так:

```
obj := reflect.New(typ);
class := obj.Elem();
method := class .MethodByName("MyMethod");
method.Call([]reflect.Value{});

func (instance *MyStruct) MyMethod() {
    log.Println("instance = ", instance);
    log.Println("*instance = ", &instance);
}
```

В лог выводит что instance = nil, а &instance как раз то значение, которым должно быть instance.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно вызвать метод?)

Comment: воспроизводимый пример покажите

Comment: Что значит правильно вызвать метод? Если вы хотите в лог вывести значение и адрес, то уберите звездочку в типе переменной метода - `func (instance MyStruct) MyMethod() {...}`

Comment: Вы в `&instance` выводите адрес указателя на ноль. Зачем?